# Dynamically render object elements in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
let abilities = data.player_info.abilities
    let summary = summarize_abiltiy(abilities)
    console.log(summary)
    document.getElementById("strength").append(
        "<span class=" + "label label-success>" + summary.strength[0][0] + ":" + summary.strength[0][1] + "</span>")
```

I am trying to dynamically render items in the `summary` object.

[image]

As you can see, the `Weak` items are hard-coded right now and the JavaScript render just got appended as a string.

```
<div id="player_name" class="price"></div>
            <div id="player_nation" class="lead"></div>
            <center id="strength"><span><strong>Strong: </strong></span>

            </center>
            <center><span><strong>Weak: </strong></span>
                <span class="label label-danger">HTML5/CSS</span>
                <span class="label label-danger">HTML5/CSS</span>
                <span class="label label-danger">HTML5/CSS</span>
                <span class="label label-danger">HTML5/CSS</span>
                <span class="label label-danger">HTML5/CSS</span>

            </center>
```

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: do you want `Strong: Agility :20` as your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question, as others have suggested `innerHTML` should solve your problem

```
document.getElementById('strength').innerHTML =
  `<span class='label label-success'>${summary.strength1}:${summary.strength2}</span>`; //string literals
```

The new [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) `append` states that it is possible to use DOMString while appending

> ParentNode.append() allows you to also append DOMString object, whereas Node.appendChild() only accepts Node objects.

So if you wish to remain with `Node.append()` i reckon the only way is to split it up further as below

```
var newSpan = document.createElement('span'); //create a node
newSpan.classList.add('label', 'label-success'); // manually add classes
newSpan.append(`${summary.strength1}:${summary.strength2}`);// here you can use append to append strings
document.getElementById('weak').append(newSpan); //can use append or appendChild here
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tejasva's answer will remove `<strong>` tag... so better you use concate

```
document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML += 
    "<span class=" + "label label-success>" + summary.strength[0][0] + ":" + summary.strength[0][1] + "</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML += 
    "<span class=" + "label label-success> Agility : 20 </span>";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center id="strength"><span><strong>Strong: </strong></span>
</center>
```

You may replace the static data with your dynamic data as per the requirement.